# How to retrieve full text from tweet using twarc2

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twarc2

I am using `twarc2` for retrieving tweets. The returned jsonl file has the following keys:

```
dict_keys(['text', 'conversation_id', 'entities', 'author_id', 'public_metrics', 'source', 'id', 'reply_settings', 'edit_history_tweet_ids', 'created_at', 'possibly_sensitive', 'lang', 'referenced_tweets', 'author', '__twarc'])
```

When I checked the value of `data[0]['text']`, it terminated with `...` like below:

```
RT @Weather_West: "You may have heard that we have 12 years to fix everything. This is well-meaning nonsense, but it’s still nonsense. We h…
```

I am wondering how can I get the full text of the tweet. Apparently, `twarc2` doesn't even return `retweeted_status` unlike `tweepy` which used to be helpful for retrieving the full text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `twarc2 csv` auto-expands the tweets. So, instead of working with `.jsonl`, one can first convert to `.csv` and then one will be able to access the full text from the tweet.